# How to compare values from two text files using common name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I'm trying to write a python script that will compare specific column entries from two text files using a common ID.

I have one text file that contains a road name, starting mileage and ending mileage like this.

Name    Begin    End

0045    0        45

0190    0        3

0006    0        190

The second text file contains many columns, three of which are of interest to me. The Name will repeat many times, and I want to compare each instance of each name to the corresponding mileages in the other text file. These will not be in any order based on Name or Mile.

Name    Mile

0045    0.05

0045    1.0

0045    5.3

0006    74.6

0006    32.1

etc

I'd like to check that the Mile in txt2 is greater than Begin from txt1, but less than End from txt2 using matching Names. Any line from txt2 that is not between Begin(txt1) and End(txt1) should be written to a third text file that is created by the script. I know how to write IF statements and read from/write to text files, but I'm really stuck on how to have it match the Names and then compare specific columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far??

Comment: A whole lot of googling. My code so far opens the two text files, creates the third, and closes them. I think I can get most of it if someone can getting me started with the parsing. I'm very much a beginner with programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data from your two files in dictionaries which are keyed by your "name" parameter.  Then you can use those names to access corresponding elements in each dictionary.

The following code is only a rough guide, I have not tried it out, it almost certainly has errors:

```
d1 = {}  # we are going to put all our file 1 data into a dict.
with open("file1")  as f: # open file 1
    for line in f:        # read each line
        key, begin, end = f.split() # this only works if there are ALWAYS three columns.
        d1[key] = (begin, end)     
#  file1 automatically closes after the "with" block

# same for file 2
d2 = {}
with open("file2")  as f:
    for line in f:       
        key, mile = f.split() 
        d2[key] = mile


common_keys = set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys())

# Here we are going to ignore all keys that are not in both
# datasets, but you can use other set operations to work with those entries.

# iterate through the common keys and fish the records out of the dictionaries.
for key in common_keys:
    begin, end = d1[key]
    mile = d2[key]

    ... now do any calculation you like with `mile`, `begin` and `end`.
```

Comment: This will just overwrite the miles in the second file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid if I understand your point correctly, then I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

The idea is to read the first file into the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `name` as a key and list of `(begin, end)` pairs as a value. Then, while reading the second file, for every line compare the mile value with the begin and end values from the name from the defaultdict we've created before. Then, if the `mile` value is not between `begin` and `end` - write it to the `output.txt`:

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = defaultdict(list)
with open('input1.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f)  # skip first line
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            items = line.split()
            data[items[0]].append(map(float, items[1:]))

with open('input2.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        next(f)  # skip first line
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                name, mile = line.split()
                mile = float(mile)
                for begin, end in data.get(name, []):
                    if not (begin <= mile <= end):
                        output_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Example:

`input1.txt`:

```
Name Begin End

0045 0 45

0190 0 3

0006 0 190
```

`input2.txt` (see some `0045` and `0006` values are out of the `begin`-`end` range):

```
Name Mile

0045 0.05

0045 1000

0045 5.3

0006 3000

0006 32.1
```

The script produces `output.txt`:

```
0045 1000
0006 3000
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! it does help, but I'm getting this error ('builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__') right away. Am I incorrectly using the defaultdict?

Comment: @user3494674 what python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

## This is the program for getting common numbers in two text files

```
from sys import argv

script, filename1, filename2 = argv

txt1 = open(filename1, 'r')
txt2 = open(filename2, 'r')

r = []

for line in txt1.readlines():
    r.append(int(line.rstrip("\n")))

for l in txt2.readlines():
    if int(l.rstrip("\n")) in r:
        print l
```

## open cmd prompt, go to location where you have stored three files and type

> > > python ".py file" filename1 filename2